# Best approach to start an Activity from ViewModel in MVVM Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am following MMVM architecture in app, Everything was working fine untill I got a crash using following code to start an activity from ViewModel. Method is called from XML using databindings and passing `view` as parameter and `getApplication()` is the method from `AndroidViewModel` class.

```
getApplication().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), MyActivity.class));
```

I believe it was because I am not using NEW_TASK flag since I am starting activity outside an Activity class.

Now there are following solutions I could think of but not sure which one is best based on architectural point of view.

**1. ViewModel with a method which takes `Activity` as parameter and call that method from a fragment**

```
public startMyActivity(Activity activity){
   activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class));
}
```

Now add a listner something like this in fragment

```
mBinding.myButton.setOnClickListener(){
    viewModel.startMyActivity(getActivity());  
}
```

**2. Adding a New Task flag to intent and keep it in ViewModel itself**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

**3. Start the Activity from fragment itself**

```
mBinding.myButton.setOnClickListener(){
   activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class));
}
```

I believe all these approaches works fine but a question in mind

Is it ok to have listeners seprately in Fragment insted of using binded ViewModels to call method from view xml ?

**I am not sure about the second approach if that will still crash the app in some OS.**

Which one is the best approach from architecture point of view and unit test prespective ?

Comment: One must avoid using any android views in ViewModel or AndroidViewModel.

Comment: @ChintanSoni I agree, It is not a reference it passes from databinding on click listeners method, I belive this should be fine.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar who should start the activity then and how because ideally all view interactions should be handled in view models.

Comment: Yes you are right, Well it depends, if you have activity context available then it's best to use, `NEW_TASK` is commonly used the activity context is not available for example in a broadcast receiver or a service etc.

Answer (score 8):

I would go for navigation inside activities/fragments but of course most case you wanna trigger your navigation from view model.
So you need to use a command from you view model to notify your view (activity/fragment) to navigate elsewhere.
You can do this kind of "command" using LiveData and more specificly [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java).

SingleLiveEvent is like any LiveData but trigger an event only when you explicity set a value to it, for example you won't receive its value when starting observing it from your view (activity/fragment)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and see if this works for me.

Comment: If I have many possible destination from the current Screen. Should I have 1 `SingleLiveEvent` for each possible destination? What's the best practice for this?

Comment: I'll go with one event and destination as argument

Comment: The link is dead...